# Odoo 12 - New Theme - Arabic - Greys Out Site

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have created a new Theme for Odoo 12 (in EN and AR), the theme works fine on my Environment. But when the theme is copied to live environment, the EN site loads fine, but the AR site goes Grey completely. Can any suggest how to approach this problem. There is no evident error in console.

Comment: Infact, when in debug mode, there are no CSS getting loaded on AR site, they all give 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, it is possible CSS, qweb and js can't loads.
please add your CSS Js and qweb properly.

I add an example for css or js load

```
<odoo>
<template id="assets_backend" name="Demo project" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
<xpath expr="." position="inside">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/module_name/static/src/css/custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/module_name/static/src/js/module_name.js"/>
</xpath>
</template>
</odoo>
```